# How to fix: else statement not being called c++

Tags: c++

SO i have this project im working on using nested if statements but my else statement sin't being called i've tried moving around brackets but have had no luck...

```cpp
cout << "WELCOME TO OLIVER'S CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADEVTURE\n\n";
cout << "Would you like to go down the hard path or the easypath? \n\n>";
cin >> R1;
if (R1 == "hard" || "Hard") {
    cout << "you chose the hard path... ";
    cout << "\nYou stumbled upona pool and a cow where do you want to go? (pool / cow) d\n\n>";
    cin >> R2;
    if (R2 == "pool" || "Pool") {
        cout << "\n\ncongrats ur swimming do you want to fight the water snake or swim away (fight / swim)";
        cout << "\n\n>";
        cin >> R4;
        if (R4 == "fight" || "Fight") {
            cout << "\n\nNice you won... ";
        }

        else {
            cout << "you swam away but you sadly drowned and i'm now upset i wanted you to win... ;(";
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "\n\nYou fought the cow... YOU WON do you want to eat it's meat? (yes or no) \n\n>";
        cin >> R5;
        if (R5 == "Yes" || "yes") {
            cout << "\n\nyou didn't cook it you die now ggs";
        }
        else {
            cout << "\n\nyou starved you die.I had my money on u y u di ?";
        }
    }
}
else {
    cout << "you chose the easy path";
```

input Easy / Easy 
output "You chose the hard path..."

Comment: `if (R1 == "hard" || "Hard"  )` should be `if (R1 == "hard" || R1 == "Hard"  )`

Comment: Blaze pointed out the error. In C++, "Hard" results in a non-zero value, which is therefore true. Hence, the if conditions are always true.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `strcmpi(r1.c_str()) == 0`, "hard").  The 'i' is for 'insensitive', or 'ignores case', though the behavior would change to accept "hArD" and "HARD" and so forth.

Comment: Convert your text string to all lower case or all upper case before comparing.  Search the internet for "c++ transform string toupper".